# Issue with Amadeus API - Invalid Query Parameter

Tags: amadeus

I am currently working with the Amadeus API to retrieve flight check-in links. However, I have encountered an issue with the API response, specifically an "INVALID OPTION" error with the detail "Invalid query parameter". I have tried different airline codes (DL, AF) but the error persists.

I have followed the documentation provided by Amadeus for authentication and API usage. I have successfully obtained an access token and included it in the header of my curl request.

Here is the curl command I am using:

```
curl -X GET "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/reference-data/urls/checkin-links?airline=AF" -H "Authorization: Bearer [access_token]"
```

I have double-checked the documentation and confirmed that the parameter "airline" is valid for this API endpoint.

I would appreciate any guidance or assistance on how to resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Assuming [this is the correct API documentation](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-check-in-links/api-reference), the query parameter is `airlineCode`, not `airline`. This can be closed as a **TYPO**

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are using the wrong parameter name.
`airlineCode` is correct instead of `airline` to input airline code in [Flight check-in Links AP](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-check-in-links)I in Amadeus Self-Service APIs.

`curl -X GET "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/reference-data/urls/checkin-links?airlineCode=BA" -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" -k`

or code example is available in GitHub: https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-code-examples/blob/master/flight_checkin_links/v2/get/curl/flight_checkin_links.sh